# How to search for Points Of Interest (POI) instead of address using Windows map API in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, maps, here-api

Is there a way to to search for Points Of Interest (POI) instead of address using Windows map API? I am developing an app for Windows Phone 8.1 and I know that `MapLocationFinder.FindLocationsAsync()` could return a response when search for addresses, but not POI.

For example, if I search for 'Starbuck' or 'McDonald' or 'Queensbay Mall', it returns nothing.

I know that some other map APIs use REST or Spatial Data Services to get POI, but I don't want to use that because I need the map to work offline (after download of the offline map to device). I could not use mapTask to get POI as I need to get a POI list returned to the app for further processing. I am certain that exists POI information besides addresses within the offline map.

Please advise on any method to get this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
 MapIcon mi = new MapIcon();
 mi.Location = new Windows.Devices.Geolocation.Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition()
 {
     Latitude = position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Latitude,
     Longitude = position.Coordinate.Point.Position.Longitude
 });
 mymap.MapElements.Add(mi);
 await mymap.TrySetViewAsync(mi.Location, 18D, 0, 0, MapAnimationKind.Bow);
 await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new Uri("bingmaps:?lvl=10&where=starbuck", UriKind.Absolute));
```

Try this...

Comment: This is using the launcher, I need the POI to be returned to my app...any idea?

Comment: Microsoft not yet released API to use offline maps. Once try using HERE maps